# Find the minimum value of the function

Tags: calculus

f:[1,2]→ℝ, where f(x)=$\sqrt{\frac{8-3x}{x}}+2\sqrt{4x+1}-\sqrt{4x^2-8x+49}$

I'm not sure what I'm suppose to do here. I think I need the derivative but once I have that where do I go from there?

Comment: HINT: Think about the change of the slope at points on $f$, perhaps you know negative slope mean the graph is decreasing(respectively positive slope mean the graph is increasing)